# TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256

Tags: solidity

help, I'm getting errors on my code saying: TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256. And I am in desperate need of help. I don't know what to do and if you need the full code pls say so

I think it has something to do with the address though I am not quite sure since I am still a beginner, so I am absolutely clueless so far. If you do know how to help me solve please say so.

```
 // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
  pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

 import './ERC721.sol';

contract ERC721Enumerable is ERC721 {

    uint256[] private _allTokens;

    // CHALLENGE! Write out mapping yourself!!

    // mapping from tokenId to position in _allTokens array
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) private _allTokensIndex;
     
    // mapping of owner to list of all owner token ids
    mapping(uint256 => uint256[]) private _ownedTokens;
      
    // mapping from token ID index of the owner tokens list
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) private _ownedTokensIndex;


    // @notice count NFTs tracked by this contract
    // @return A count of valid NFTs tracked by this contract, where each on of
    // them has an assigned and queryable ower not equal to the zero address


    // @notice Enumerate valid NFT's
    // @dev Throws if '_index" >= 'totalSupply()'.
    // @param _index A couter less than 'totalSupply()'
    // @return The token identifier for the '_index'th NFt,
    // (sort order not specified)

    //function tokenByIndex(uint256 _index) external view returns (uint256);

    // @notice Enumerate NFTs assigned to an owner
    // @dev Throws if '_index' >= 'balanceOf(_owner)' or if
    // '_owner' is the zero address, representing invalid NFTs.
    // @param _owner An address where we are interested in NFTs owned by them
    // @param _index A counter less than 'balanceOf(_owner)'
    // @return The token identifier for the '_index'th NFT assigned to '_owner',
    // (sort order not specfied)

    //function tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address _owner, uint256 _index) external view returns (uint256);

    function _mint(address to, uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721) {
        super._mint(to, tokenId);
        // 2 things!
        // a. add tokens too the owner
        // b. all tokens to out totalSupply - allToken
        _addTokensToAllTokenEnumeration(tokenId);   
        _addTokensToOwnerEnumeration(to, tokenId);
    }

    // add tokens to the _allTokens array and set the position of the tokens indexes

    function _addTokensToAllTokenEnumeration(uint256 tokenId) private {
        _allTokensIndex[tokenId] = _allTokens.length;
        _allTokens.push(tokenId);
    }

    // two function - one that returns token by the index
    // another one thata retruns tokenByOwnerIndex

    function tokenByIndex(uint256 index) public view returns(uint256) {
        // make sure that the undex is not our of bounds of the
        // total supply
        require(index < totalSupply(), 'global index is out of bounds');
        return _allTokens[index];
    }

     // return the total supply of the _allTokens array

     function totalSupply() public view returns(uint256) {
        return _allTokens.length;
    }

    function _addTokensToOwnerEnumeration(address to, uint256 tokenId) public {
       _ownedTokensIndex[tokenId] = _ownedTokens[to].length;
        _ownedTokens[to].push(tokenId);
    }
     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, your mapping is wrong. In your function _addTokensToOwnerEnumeration() you have taken address as mapping key. but in your declaration you have taken

```
//this is wrong as per you have used in your function
mapping(uint256=> uint256[]) private _ownedTokens; 


// You have to declare like this.
mapping(address=>uint256[]) private _ownedTokens;
```

Answer (score 0):

`_ownedTokens` have `uint256` as key type it should be `address` type:

```
// mapping of owner to list of all owner token ids
mapping(address => uint256[]) private _ownedTokens;
```